# How to force GCC to produce REPNE SCAS (x86 assembly), not CMP?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I have this code:

```
void main () {
    short int a[5]={12,15,1,17,248};
    short int i=0;
    short int b=17;
    for (;i<(sizeof a/sizeof *a);i++) {
        if (a[i]==b) printf("Hello, %d\n",i);
    }
}
```

And i expect to see REPE SCASW in the generated assembly code. 
But regardless of the level of optimization (i tried -O 0,1,2,3) GCC generates simply loop with cmp and je, such as (i got it with objdump):

```
  3f:   48 83 fb 05             cmp    rbx,0x5
  43:   74 2b                   je     70 <main+0x70>
        if (a[i]==b) printf("Hello, %d\n",i);
  45:   66 83 3c 5c 11          cmp    WORD PTR [rsp+rbx*2],0x11
  4a:   75 ec                   jne    38 <main+0x38>
```

Who can tell me, why GCC doesnt use REPNE SCAS x86 instruction in such simple case? Maybe, scas is too slow comparing to the loop with 2 "cmp"s and 2 "je"s?

And can i force GCC to use SCAS with REPNE prefix anyway?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you even care?

Comment: Don't you mean `repne scas`?

Comment: "Don't you mean repne scas"
Yes, of course, sorry.

Comment: You can't convince it to generate non-optimal code.  Agner Fogs' instruction tables tells you that REPNE SCAS takes 6n micro-ops, CMP+JNE takes (1+1)n micro-ops.  Small risc-like instructions perform better on modern cores.

Comment: If we look at [Agners Fog's instruction tables](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) and use the Nehalem microarchitecture as an example, we see that `REP SCAS` has a latency of `40+2n`. So there's a fairly large latency regardless of the number of elements you're scanning. If the compiler generated a loop with a `REPNE SCASW` inside to find the next element that equals `b` you could end up with pretty poor performance, especially if `b` is found frequently in the array.

Comment: Did you try with `-Os`?  You'd only want `repne scas` if optimizing for code-size, **not** speed.  `rep movs/rep stos` are optimized and run very fast if the inputs satisfy some requirements, but it turns out there isn't a similarly-optimized microcoded `strchr` implementation behind `repne scas`

Comment: If this is on a hosted implementation, that is, with an OS your program is running on, `void main()` is not strictly-conforming. Use `int main()` to make it strictly-conforming.

Comment: Actually, even `-Os` doesn't use `repne scas`.  http://goo.gl/aFKy3c.  I only looked at gcc 5.2.  `-O3` makes smaller code than `-Os` for `main`, because it sees through the loop and only makes code for the one hit.  Factoring the loop out into a separate function, `-O3` does make bigger code with more branches.  Never use `main` for looking at optimized compiler output.  gcc on purpose optimizes it less, and marks it as "cold".

Comment: To answer the specific question "Can i force GCC to use SCAS with REPNE prefix anyway?". Technically yes, hand code the sub-optimal solution using inline assembler. Although I have a suspicion this isn't what you intended ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't indicate why you seem to think that you should see `REPNE SCAS`, but regardless of optimization level you should not see it.

If you refer to the [Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) tables (last updated in 2014) you'll find that `REPNE SCAS` is *always* less optimal than a `CMP` followed by a `JE`.

You really can't force the compiler to go this route, but if you need to produce that specific code you would then be best served to go the inline assembly route.

Comment: Cycle counting is fraught with peril, but generally speaking, string instructions haven't been a good choice for speed optimization for anything after the 386.  :-)